# Is it possible in Eclipse to define a set of breakpoints and only have them fire after a given event happens?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'd like to set a set of breakpoints in a couple of tight loops.. but I just want them to fire after a given event occurs.

The problem lies in the fact that all those breakpoints are defined in a very low level module, so they can't know when that high level event is raised.

It'd be perfect if I could set a special conditional breakpoint in the high level code, such that after that breakpoint condition was met it would, from that moment on, start firing any other breakpoints found in the program (I don't particularly care for that high level breakpoint, though).

Is there any way to accomplish something like this? If not, how to circumvent this limitation? The only way that comes to mind would be to define a temporary singleton to keep state and have my low level breakpoints depend on that singleton's flag.

Comment: Pretty sure the only way to do this is to set the high-level breakpoint, then when you hit that, set the low-level ones. Which will be crap if you have to do it loads.

Comment: @Russell: that's precisely my problem. I'm sure I'll have to do it loads of times, so it'll get pretty tiresome.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at the code that fires the event? In this case, you can use a breakpoint there to set a property to be checked by your low level breakpoints. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38055032/287976

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on `breakpoint properties` you will see plenty of options

[image: breakpoint properties]

Comment: I'm not sure how this in any way answers the question.

Comment: you can find a high level condition that could be reached by `this.` or `session.getAttribute(...)` or in any other way then you might just need to add the condition and debugger would break when condition is met

Answer (score 0):

You can make creative use of assertions, but they are disabled in Eclipse by default.

Here's a good link explaining how to enable assertions: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit594-2004/Pages/eclipse-faq.html#assert

And here's more info on how to use them for your purposes: http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/using-java-assertions-use

From the article:

> Eclipse has a very useful mechanism for breaking on Exceptions. It's a
>   different kind of breakpoint, which is triggered when the exception is
>   thrown, regardless of how (and if) it is caught. If you are using
>   assertions, I highly recommend setting a breakpoint on assertion
>   failures when debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking several different questions here.

In answer to "Q: can I set a breakpoint that triggers when some event occurs", you might want to look at "watch points":

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

The same article discusses a possible answer to another of your questions: "Q: ... after that breakpoint condition was met it would, from that moment on, start firing other breakpoints..."

Look for "breakpoint properties", in the same article.

'Hope that helps!

PS:
Here's one other short - but very good - article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Comment: The problem, as stated in the OP, is that breakpoint properties by themselves won't help me a lot -- low level modules don't have access to the high level info that would allow them to know when to fire.