# Eclipse conditional breakpoint - only after other breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm debugging an application that does a lot of method calling. I want to, for example, debug `methodA`. It is called 1000 times.

But, in my main loop, I only want to start debugging method A after a few statements.

```
public void methodA()
{
    //does something nasty that I want to debug
}
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        methodA();
    }
    methodB();
    methodA();
}
```

I want to start breaking in `methodA` **only after** `methodB` is called. I don't really want to change my code (say, inserting a `boolean` value and making the breakpoint conditional on that `boolean`).

Is something like this possible in Eclipse? Or are there better options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A) Simply use hit count as 1000.**

Its works only if the methodA inside for loop is NOT under some condition.

**B) Using condition**

Put the break point at the first statement inside methodA.Refer image

**[Here methodA == test and I put break point at line number 14]**

[image]

Right click on the breakpoint and select `Breakpoint properties` option and add the below condition.

```java
StackTraceElement[] stacktrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
StackTraceElement e = stacktrace[2];
return (e.getLineNumber() == 9);
```

Here 9 means the line number where second call to methodA(or test) is made.Find out the same in your code and change this.

Check the javadoc for [StackTraceElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) and instead of line number you can also use method name also. i.e you can break only when it is calling from the function `xyz`.

[image]

**C) Wait for eclipse Oxygen (4.7)**

In next version of eclipse JDT will provide trigger points on breakpoints. So you can say hit breakpoint ***y*** ONLY IF breakpoint ***x*** was hit before.

With this you can pause on a breakpoint ONLY on a given methods flow [stacktrace].

Ex: You can stop on a breakpoint only when call flow is:

`methodA() --> methodB() --> methodC() --> methodD()` NOT on

`methodA() --> methodC() --> methodD()` etc.

See this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495957) for more details. Add your comments/suggestion to this bug.

Comment: @RobAu Edited my answer and added one more method. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @Chandrayya, I look forward to it

Comment: The feature is called "Trigger Point" in Eclipse Oxygen and it does exactly what is described here. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

I use system properties to achieve that.

### The example

Suppose we have this class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            methodA();
        }
        methodB();
        methodA();
    }

    private static void methodA() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    private static void methodB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

}
```

We want to add a breakpoint inside `methodA()`, but only stop at it after calling `methodB()`, but without adding extra variables to code or using counters.

### A breakpoint to set a property

First, let's add a breakpoint inside `methodB()` and make it condition. In its condition, we will set a system property to `true`. We do not want to pause inside `methodB()`, so the condition will return `false`:

```
System.setProperty("enable.methodA.breakpoint", "true");
return false;
```

See the GIF below:

[image: Adding first condition to <code>methodB()</code>]

### A breakpoint that checks the property

Now, we add a breakpoint to `methodA()`, also with a condition. In the condition, we first get the value of the set system property:

```
String p = System.getProperty("enable.methodA.breakpoint", "false");
```

Then, we parse it as a boolean and return it:

```
return Boolean.valueOf(p).booleanValue();
```

(Note that the default value is `"false"`, so the breakpoint will not pause if the property is not set.)

Check this step in the GIF below:

[image: Add bookmark that checks system property.]

### Running

Now, if we run this class in debug mode, the bookmark at `methodA()` will only pause after `methodB()` is called:

[image: <code>methodA()</code> is only paused after <code>methodB()</code>]

### Disabling the breakpoint again

If `methodA()` is called many, many times after `methodB()` and we only want to check it once, we can unset the property eventually. For example, suppose our `main()` method is like this one now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        methodA();
    }
    methodB();
    methodA();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        methodA();
    }
}
```

We can use this condition, where we set the property back to false so to avoid stopping at this breakpoint again:

```
String p =
    System.getProperty("enable.methodA.breakpoint", "false");

System.setProperty("enable.methodA.breakpoint", "false");

return Boolean.valueOf(p).booleanValue();
```

This is, of course, only a simple example — the sky is the limit with this trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional breakpoint in eclipse for variable value based conditions.

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-condition_option.htm

Comment: Then I need to modify my code to be able to use a variable with a value. I don't want to do that (as stated in my question), and I'm looking for other options (if here are)

Comment: if your methodB() doesn't change any of your variables, this solution isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a breakpoint on `methodA`, and when you hit that breakpoint, add your second breakpoint to `methodB` and continue execution.

Comment: That is what I do now, and is inefficient as I need to find the breakpoints, enable them, disable them etc.

Comment: @RobAu If you're transitioning only once per execution, it's not much effort. If you're doing it multiple times, how do you expect Eclipse to know when to "revert" to the pre-`methodB` state?

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
public void methodA()
{
    //does something nasty that I want to debug
}
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        methodA();
    }
    methodB(); //first breakpoint here? 
    methodA(); //2nd breakpoint here?
}
```