# Eclipse conditional breakpoint templates?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

After more years than I care to remember using Eclipse I've only just come across conditional breakpoints. They've already been very useful, but it's occurred to me that you may end up writing the same conditions over and over again. Is there any way to create some standard templates for conditions? For instance, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725254/eclipse-conditional-breakpoint-only-after-other-breakpoint) has a great example of a condition that would be a contender for templating, line numbers/method names etc would be substituted rather than writing the entire condition again. The idea would be that these templates are shared across an entire team. Is this something that is currently possible in Eclipse? If not, would it be possible to write some kind of plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not currently possible. 
You can however reuse a previously entered condition.
Honestly something more compilcated seems overkill to me, I have known  this feature for maybe 10 years and never feel the need for that. In practice I never used something more complicated than one or two equals conditions.
 Plus I would even argue that if you end up debugging regularly a similar piece of code,  you have either more general coding quality or organisationnal problems.

Comment: Unfortunately in the real world quality and organisation problems are often beyond my control. There's a few situations that come up repeatedly that this sort of thing would help with, for example maybe you want to debug a common service or DAO, but only when it's been called from a particular place. This sort of thing comes up very often in the system I currently work on.The idea would not be to chain together lots of conditions, I agree that would be overkill. What I'm thinking about is more like a template that allows you to add a "called by" condition with one or two clicks.