# Stop debugging point if called method throws Exception in IntelliJ debugger for Java Code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have method1,method2, and method3. When method3 is throwing exception then I want to stop the debugger in method2 how to do that in IntelliJ for Java Code. I know how to do conditional debugging but this one based on the called method exception.

```
method1(){
   method2();
}

method2(){
.....
  calling in loop method3();
.....
.....
}

method3(){
....
.. throws Exception

}
```

Comment: Have you tried going line by line in method 2 until it hits method 3 or the exception?

Comment: thanks for the reply which loops more than 100 times which is hard to go line by line for the method which has 100s of lines.

Comment: You can use techniques described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30753631/461499

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint?